# How to connect two databases at the same time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, connection

How to connect to two databases at the same time in SQL Server?
i want to create a query from a local database db1 on some tables exist in an outside database db2. Im working with SQL Server.

Comment: You don't need two connection, you can join cross database tables in your query

Comment: `db1` and `db2` are in the same `SQL Server` ?

Comment: It's not clear from your post, but do you actually mean 2 separate Instances? A single instance can host many databases, thus to reference a different database just use 3 part naming: `DBName.SchemaName.ObjectName`.

Comment: chech this link https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2855/sql-server-multi-database-query-with-registered-servers/

Comment: db1 is a local database and db2 is installed on hostgator.

Comment: use `Linked Server` as suggested in the Answer . Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine for further information

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servers will need to be connected as a Linked Server in Server Objects, Linked Servers with a user that has access to both servers.